# How to adjust font-size property based on the width of the div?

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-4

How to adjust font-size property based on the div width using only CSS. It should be able to change its size based on the width of the div.

Comment: What have you achieved?

Comment: This StackOverflow post has your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056591/font-scaling-based-on-width-of-container

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Font scaling based on width of container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056591/font-scaling-based-on-width-of-container)